# What is the proper structure for the execution of network-bootstrapper.jar?

Tags: corda

Our team is trying to execute

```
`java -jar network-bootstrapper.jar <nodes-root-dir>`
```

to bootstrap a Corda node.  The documentation on [Bootstrapping the network](https://docs.corda.net/head/setting-up-a-corda-network.html#bootstrapping-the-network) instructs the reader to:

```
To use it, create a directory containing a node.conf file for each node >you want to create. Then run the following command:

java -jar network-bootstrapper.jar <nodes-root-dir>

For example running the command on a directory containing these files :

.
├── notary.conf             // The notary's node.conf file
├── partya.conf             // Party A's node.conf file
└── partyb.conf             // Party B's node.conf file

Would generate directories containing three nodes: notary, partya and partyb.
```

We have

1. Created a root directory.
2. Placed the network-bootstrapper.jar in the root directory.
3. Created a notary.conf
4. Created a partya.conf
5. Executed `java -jar network-bootstrapper.jar <nodes-root-dir>`

This results in "No nodes found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing NetworkBootstrapper source we realized that the documentation was incorrect ...

1. The exception was a little misleading. The correction to the 'No nodes found' exception was placing the corda.jar in the nodes-root-dir.
2. Step 1 gets you further.  The second issue to resolve is creating the .conf file with the right naming convention.  The documentation indicates that the naming convention for the node (entities) is [node directory name].conf.  The NetworkBootstrapper code base revealed that the naming convention that it expected was [node directory name]_node.config.

Comment: Placing the corda.jar where? Your first step seems to have been cut off.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrapper reported `No nodes found` because the nodes' `node.conf` files did not end in the suffix `_node.config`. The docs are being updated to reflect this requirement in this pull request: github.com/corda/corda/pull/2848.

The first step listed in evh69's answer - placing the Corda JAR in the nodes folder - is not necessary. The bootstrapper will automatically extract its own copy of the Corda JAR as required.

Comment: Thanks Joel.  Should have read: 'The correction to the 'No nodes found' exception was placing the corda.jar in the nodes-root-dir.'   You are correct.  We were confused by our trial and error method to get the config right.  With the corda.jar missing we would have been informed:

'No corda jar found in root directory. Extracting from jar'

I do think it would be good to add the details that the corda.jar should be placed in nodes-root-dir to [Bootstrapping the network](https://docs.corda.net/head/setting-up-a-corda-network.html#bootstrapping-the-network) documentation.